# gradle.properties file is missing from .gradle folder in windows

Tags: gradle, build-tools

I have installed gradle with [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) package manager, but in *.gradle* directory there is no *gradle.properties* file. Do I need to re-install gradle? or what should I write besides what I need to add in *grdle.properties* file If I will create it?

P.S: I use gradle plugin in Spring Tool Suite, and I need to add something in the *gradle.properties* file concerning the project

Comment: you can create the `gradle.properties` file yourself, Gradle will not necessarily create this file during installation. Note that you have several places where you create/configure `gradle.properties`files : see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

Comment: Thanks @M.Ricciuti

Comment: you're welcome . I created an answer from my comment, to mark this question as "resolved', if you want to accept this answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The propery file `gradle.properties` is not created automatically during Gradle installation. You can create this file manually and add your specific configuration into it. Note that there are two places where you can create a `gradle.properties` file, as described in documentation [Gradle configuration properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)